# Integracão TFS com DreamWeaver

Tags: team-foundation-server, dreamweaver

Estou instalando o TFS 2012 em um dos servidores da empresa e surgiu uma dívida, pesquisei na net, mas não achei nada muito conclusivo... bom gostaria de saber se da para usar TFS com o DreamWeaver ?

Answer (score 1):

Sim, dá! Só não terá integração nativa com o software, então você vai ter que usar por linha de comando ou instalar o Power Tools e usar a integração com o Windows Explorer, que cria os comandos no menu de contexto.

Comment: Irei tentar, mas caso de algum erro irei pedir para ele instalar o eclipse que vi que seria mais simples....

Comment: Se você pode usar o Eclipse melhor, já que o Team Explorer tem uma versão em plug-in para a IDE totalmente integrada, então sua experiência será como se estivesse no Visual Studio